# Function that will perform the same ETL on specific column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, function

I am finding the index of today's data if it is different than yesterday's data one column at a time.  I have some steps that will find the change of one column ('Payrate1'), locate the indices and create a dataframe with the intended output.  I'm making dictionaries because sometimes my source data will have more or less rows from two different days, so the ID key/value pair is best.

How do I make this into a function I can pass to all the payrate columns?  (my source data has 10 columns of payrate data, all named a different column)

```
  

     import pandas as pd
     data = {'Employee': ['Tom','Jas'],
        'ID' : [1050, 9811],`
        'Payrate1': [20,28],`
        'Payrate2': [20,22]} `
         yesterday = pd.DataFrame(data)

    data2 = {'Employee': ['Tom','Jas'], 
         'ID' : [1050, 9811],
         'Payrate1': [25,28],`
         'Payrate2': [20,24]} 
    today = pd.DataFrame(data2)

    ###make dictionaries for today and yesterday to compare
    y_id=yesterday['ID']
    t_id=today['ID']
    y_id_pay=yesterday['Payrate1']
    t_id_pay=today['Payrate1']
    t_pay_id_dict=dict(zip(t_id,t_id_pay))
    y_pay_id_dict=dict(zip(y_id,y_id_pay))
    y_p_i=y_pay_id_dict.values()
    t_p_i=t_pay_id_dict.values()
     
     #### get indecies if any value has changed
    pay_diff_idx = [index for index, element in enumerate(t_p_i) if element not in y_p_i]

     #### make desired output dataframe
    df=today[today.index.isin(pay_diff_idx)]
```

So instead of copying all this code and removing 'Payrate1' and replacing it with 'Payrate2' - how can I make a function that changes the Column Name to what I need and return a unique dataframe?

I tried putting all the code in a function, and making a variable to pass into the function. I don't know exactly what I'm doing wrong:

```
    def pay_rate_etl():

          ###make dictionaries for today and yesterday to compare
          y_id=yesterday['ID']
          t_id=today['ID']
          y_id_pay=yesterday[pay_column]
          t_id_pay=today[pay_column]
          t_pay_id_dict=dict(zip(t_id,t_id_pay))
          y_pay_id_dict=dict(zip(y_id,y_id_pay))
          y_p_i=y_pay_id_dict.values()
          t_p_i=t_pay_id_dict.values()
     
    #### get indecies if any value has changed
          pay_diff_idx = [index for index, element in enumerate(t_p_i) if element not in y_p_i]`

     #### make desired output dataframe`
          df=today[today.index.isin(pay_diff_idx)]`


pay_column='Payrate2'
pay_rate_etl()
df2=df`

pay_column='Payrate3'
pay_rate_etl()
df3=df
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a very useful solution for my needs in the module DictDiffer

```
import dictdiffer

for diff in list(dictdiffer.diff(t_pay_id_dict, y_pay_id_dict)):        
    print(diff)
```

this module returns if there is a change, addition, or an key:value pair removed - serves my needs best.

To work around defining a function to pass in the different column 10 times, I just combined all the columns into one dictionary and used dictdiffer to find the specific kind of "difference" I need.  The DictDiffer Module is more powerful than dictionary comprehension as that only works for 'flat' dictionaries.  Mine becomes a list of dictionaries.  The output is not only any changes, but what ID is associated with the change, which of my ten payrate columns (two in example), and the value it changed to and from.

```
enter code here
rate_tiers=['Payrate1','Payrate2']

dict_yesterday = {}
dict_today= {}
for name in rate_tiers:
    rate=yesterday[name]
    rate_today=today[name]

    rate_n=yesterday['ID']
    rate_n_today=today['ID']

    dict_yesterday[name] = dict(zip(rate_n,rate))
    dict_today[name] = dict(zip(rate_n_today,rate_today))

rate_diff=[]
for diff_rates in list(dictdiffer.diff(dict_today,dict_yesterday)):         
#         if len(diff)>0:
    rate_diff.append(diff_rates)
print(rate_diff)
```